# @OneToMany Populating NULL in foreign key of Child table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have Created a User obj and Post object. Then I populated user object with post object. And finally I saved only User object. I am saving only user and expecting post to be save internally.

I searched for the solution, but people saving the objects separately. I don't want to do that.

My Entity Classes,

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer userId;
    @Column(name = "uname")
    private String userName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Post> post;

    //Getters and Setters
}


@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer postId;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    User user;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

And the Below i am trying.

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String... a) {

    String userName = "", description = "";
    int userId = 14, postId = 12;
    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    int postNo = 25;
    userName = "User " + postNo;
    posts.add(new Post(postNo + "th Post by " + userName));
    insertUserAndPost(userName, posts);
}



private static void insertUserAndPost(String userName, List<Post> posts) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("Saving User, Post should get saved automatically!");
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName(userName);

    user.setPost(posts);

    Serializable id = session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    displayUser(Integer.parseInt(id.toString()));

}
```

DB Result:

```
User:

|     24 | Abdul 22     |

Post:

|     16 | 22th Post by User 22 |   NULL |
```

Why the NULL has been inserted to foreign key in post table?
Please help

Comment: Duplicated question. Please check out the link for answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521659/foreign-key-not-stored-in-child-entity-one-to-many

Comment: use @Transactional in your method

Comment: and NO, that is NOT the JPA API, so remove the `jpa` tag